# Persist user session with cookie in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: cookies, authorization, blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

How can I persist user session between user usages of the application (closed browser/tab without logout)?
Can a Blazor WebAssembly app persist the user session in a cookie with some expiration date?

Right now I got this startup configuration, and everything related to authorization with IdentityServer works fine. The tokens in Identity Server have a 30 days expiration period.

```cs
// startup.cs
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "RoleName";
});
```

```json
// appsettings.json
"Local": {
    "Authority": "https://idserver.url",
    "ClientId": "Client",
    "DefaultScopes": [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "roles",
        "offline_access"
    ],
    "ResponseType": "code",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:5004/authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5004/authentication/login-callback"
}
```

Is there a way to persist user session in cookies?

Answer (score 1):

I will try my best to answer your question, because I had the same issue and figured it out.

So essentially in between sessions, the cookie is still there saved in the browser, and even though your `AuthenticationStateProvider` is not set to authenticated, if you try and execute a call against your API, the Cookie Handler will include the cookie in the request and it will authenticate.

So I was able to implement a solution based off an article that I found here:
https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2022/04/blazorwasm-cookie-series-part-1-blazor-webassembly-cookie-authentication.html

I assume that you have a delegation handler that attaches the cookie to outgoing HTTP requests like so:

```
public class CookieHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This guy will continue to attach that cookie in between sessions.

The problem is that the `AuthenticationStateProvider` will not persist his state. So what I did was save a local variable into the local browser storage that allows me to remember if I am authenticated. When I check if I am logged in, I make the following checks:

1. I check if the `AutenticationStateProvider` is authenticated.
2. If not, I check if I have set a local variable in the local storage indicating if I am authenticated. If that local variable exists, then he will make an API call to my web service asking for my user information. If that call completes successfully, then I update my `AuthenticationStateProvider`

I have a dependency injection service I call `ILoginService` that has an implementation that looks a bit like so:

```
ILocalStorageService _storageService;
AuthenticationStateProvider _authStateProvider;

public UserModel User { get; private set; } = new UserModel();

public LoginService(ILocalStorageService storageService, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider) : base(clientFactory)
{
    _authStateProvider = authStateProvider;
    _storageService = storageService;
}

public async Task<bool> IsLoggedIn()
{
    var authState = await _authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    if (authState.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    var isauthenticated = await _storageService.GetItemAsync<string>("isauthenticated");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(isauthenticated))
    {
        using (var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("API"))
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/login");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                UserModel? user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(jsonStr);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    await _storageService.RemoveItemAsync("isauthenticated");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    (_authStateProvider as CustomAuthStateProvider)?.SetAuthInfo(user);
                    this.User = user;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    await _storageService.RemoveItemAsync("isauthenticated");
    return false;
}

public async Task<bool> Login(LoginCredentials credentials)
{
    try
    {
        if (credentials == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(credentials));

        using (var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("API"))
        {
            StringContent body = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/login", body);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                UserModel? user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(jsonStr);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    await _storageService.RemoveItemAsync("isauthenticated");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    (_authStateProvider as CustomAuthStateProvider)?.SetAuthInfo(user);
                    this.User = user;
                    await _storageService.SetItemAsync<string>("isauthenticated", "true");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
#if DEBUG
                string responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
#endif  
                await _storageService.RemoveItemAsync("isauthenticated");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        await _storageService.RemoveItemAsync("isauthenticated");
        return false;
    }
}

public async Task<bool> Logout()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("API"))
        {
            var response = await client.DeleteAsync("/login");
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
#if DEBUG
                string responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
#endif
            }
        }

        (_authStateProvider as CustomAuthStateProvider)?.ClearAuthInfo();

        await _storageService.RemoveItemAsync("isauthenticated");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you fix your problem and anybody else that comes along.